# Appcelerator Titanium Desktop app vs. Adobe AIR: How to generate an MSI installer for a project for 32-bit and 64-bit machines?

Tags: air, windows-installer, titanium, desktop-application, appcelerator

I am trying to find out how (if possible) can I create an MSI for my Desktop project in Titanium! Do you know if Adobe AIR has a similar option and/or is it better implemented? What would you recommend me to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create MSI and DMG both in Titanium for your desktop project. In recent version they are providing builds from their server. So once you start packaging your desktop app in titanium they will upload all resources to their server and their server will create MSI and/or DMG for you and once packaging process is over they will return you the link to download your packaged application.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I chose **Deploy**, then **Distribute - Desktop** and made the config settings and I got a link to download the MSI!